# Receive data from external php script?

Tags: php

please could someone help me?

I have made a php script on my site, that will receive get data, and then return either true or false based on that get data.

I need a way to call that script through php on a completely different server, and then save the returned value.

How would I go about doing this?

Also, how would I go about doing it with POST as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL to call script on other server and also post data to that script.

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://example.com/post.php';
$fields = array(
            'data1' => urlencode($data1),
            'data2' => urlencode($data2),
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

More details you will get here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it for GET:

```
$response = file_get_contents('your_url_here');
```

And for POST, I'd use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).